# Ordering items by length in IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: .net, linq

I have a `IEnumerable<T>` collection with Name and FullName as items in it. There are around 5000 items in it.

I want to display the FullNames sorted by its lenght, so first the longest name to the shortest name displays. How can I do it in most optimized manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is effectively the same as spoon16's but without using a query expression. I generally don't use a query expression for single operations (e.g. *just* an ordering, or *just* a filter, or *just* a projection). I figured it would be good to see the alternatives :)

```
var orderedList = nameList.OrderByDescending(x => x.FullName.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have some more information about exactly what your data structures look like.  But I think that this LINQ query should get you started.

```
var orderedItems = from name in nameList
                   order by name.FullName.Length descending
                   select name;
```

Here is a whole set of [LINQ Order By examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756.aspx).

Comment: Actually I receive a 'var nameList' from the user which supports IEnumerable<T>. The nameList contains data in the following format:

Name="Jon" FullName="Jon Terry"
Name="Sil" FullName="Sil Marchiu"

and so on..

Comment: ok, so the query I have given you here should work.  if you are having problems with it throw up some example code in your question and we can address.

Comment: I think you want to add "descending" to the end of the order by clause here, to get the longest names first. Also "order by" should be "orderby".